# laravel 5.2 - check if field is empty or not

Tags: laravel, passwords, field

I want to check if some field is empty or not. If is empty, the user can update the profile without change the current password.
If is not empty, store new value of password. My controller is:

```
public function storeUpdatedUser(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required', 'name' => 'required', 'surname' => 'required', ]);

    $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
    $user->update($request->all());
    $new_password = false;

    if($new_password != ""){
        $new_password = bcrypt($request->new_password);
        $user->password = $new_password;
    }

    $user->save();
    Session::flash('flash_message', 'User updated!');

    return redirect('/');           
}
```

but dont work, no password change if I put some value 
image explain better
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```php
public function storeUpdatedUser(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required', 'name' => 'required', 'surname' => 'required', ]);

    $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
    $user->update($request->all());

    if(!empty($request->input('new_password'))) {
        $new_password = bcrypt($request->input('new_password'));
        $user->password = $new_password;
        $user->save();
    }

    Session::flash('flash_message', 'User updated!');

    return redirect('/');           
}
```

Comment: i try thank you, but don't work, old password still alive

Comment: request()->has('new_password') is cleaner in my eyes

Comment: @shigg thought: what if value of new_password is 0 ? :-O

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel Check Request Input Exists**

```
if($request->has('new_password ')) {
    dd('new_password is exists.');
} else {
    dd('new_password is not exists.');
}
```

**Laravel Check Request Input Field Empty or not**

```
if($request->filled('new_password ')) {
    dd('new_password is not empty.');
} else {
    dd('new_password is empty.');
}
```

**Laravel Check Request Input Field Empty or not**

```
if(!empty($request->input('new_password '))) {
    dd('new_password is not empty.');
} else {
    dd('new_password is empty.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me in Laravel 5.7:

```
$user = Auth::user();    
$user->update($request->filled('password') ? $request->all() : $request->except(['password']));
```